# Re-Using openCL Program

Tags: opencl

I wrote an openCl program that is to be executed several times during run-time. I was wondering if I could build it once and then just enter different arguments when needed. Will this work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  You just need to repeat the clSetKernelArg and clEnqueuNDRangeKernel calls each time you want to use the kernel.